# What does `Sitzber. Heidelberg Akad. Wiss., Math.-Naturw. Klasse. Abt. A' stand for?

Tags: reference-request, math-history

I would like to cite an article from 1914 by Oskar Perron without any abbreviations. I am unable to figure out what `Sitzber. Heidelberg Akad. Wiss., Math.-Naturw. Klasse. Abt. A' is short for. Can anyone here perhaps help me with this?

Comment: The journal (whose full name is given in Martin R's answer) doesn't seem to be listed in MathSciNet's *Abbreviations of Names of Serials* ([pdf](https://mathscinet.ams.org/msnhtml/serials.pdf)). Can anyone provide an explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is “Sitzungsberichte der Heidelberger Akademie der Wissenschaften, Mathematisch-Naturwissenschaftliche Klasse: Abteilung A, Mathematisch-physikalische Wissenschaften” – [Source](https://digi.hadw-bw.de/view/sbhadwmnkl_a_1914_14)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @David  The verbatim translation of “Sitzungsberichte” is “meeting reports,” I think the corresponding english term is “Proceedings of the Heidelberg Academy of Sciences ...”